# How to prove if $P(A \cup B ) \subseteq P (A) \cup P(B)$ then either $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $A$ and $B$ be any sets, such that $P(A \cup B) \subseteq P(A) \cup P(B)$,

2. $A \cup B \in P( A \cup B$)

2.1 Then $A \cup B\in  P(A) \cup P( B )$ ( by definition of subset)

2.2 Then $A \cup B\in  P(A)$ or $A \cup B\in P( B )$( by definition of or)

2.3 $A\cup B \subseteq A $ or $A\cup B \subseteq B$ ( by definition of power set)

2.4 Suppose $A\cup B \subseteq A $

2.5  $B \subseteq B$

2.6  $B \subseteq A$ $\cup B$ ( by definition of union)

2.7 Let $x\in B$, then we have $x \in A \cup B $ ( by definition of subset)

2.8 Since $x\in A \cup B $ , we have $x\in A$ ( from 2.4 and by definition of subset)

2.9 Therefore we have $B \subseteq A$ ( since $ x\in B$ and $x\in A $)

3. Similarly, we can prove $A\subseteq B$ using $A\cup B \subseteq B$ .
4. Therefore, we have prove that  if $P(A \cup B ) \subseteq P (A) \cup P(B)$ then either $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$

(Part 2.5-2.8 is unecessary, because my professor said that since he did not teach transistivity property of set in his class, we can't directly use it in our proof)

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I don't see how you go from 2.4 to 2.5, seeing as $A\subseteq A\lor A\subseteq B$ is true when $A\subseteq B$ is false as well.

Comment: Then how do i go from 2.4 to 2.5??

Comment: You don't.${}{}$

Comment: You don't.${}{}$

Comment: Wait, my whole proof is wrong??

Comment: We're sorry to inform you that that is the case.

Comment: So how do i start??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Since $A\cup B\in P(A\cup B)\subseteq P(A)\cup P(B)$, we know that either $A\cup B\in P(A)$ or $A\cup B\in P(B)$.

Comment: Oh so A U B ⊆ A but i was stuck here:  A ⊆ A or B ⊆ A , how do i prove that B ⊆ A  in this case?

Comment: If $A\cup B\subseteq A$, since $B\subseteq A\cup B$, we have $B\subseteq A$ by transitivity.

Comment: how do we get B⊆A∪B ?

Comment: Oh from B ⊆ A  right?

Comment: @milly The reason why we have $B \subseteq A \cup B$ is because $A \cup B = \{x \mid x \in A \lor x \in B\}$. If you take arbitrary $x \in B$, by definition of the union, $x \in A \cup B$

Comment: @milly $B\subseteq A\cup B$ is automatic, by definition. We cannot use $B\subseteq A$, because this is what we are trying to prove.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how B⊆A∪B ,becomes B⊆A by transitivity?

Comment: coz we are not supposed to cite transistivity in our exercise(it is not covered in lecture)

Comment: @milly Transitivity is obvious; it is just saying that if $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y\subseteq Z$, then $X\subseteq Z$. In this case, we know that $B\subseteq A\cup B$ and $A\cup B\subseteq A$, so that $B\subseteq A$.

Comment: ok, I will edit my solution and post it afterwards to double confirm again, thanks!

Comment: @KentaS I have edited my solution, could you please spare some time and check again for me?? Appreciated, thank q very much!!!

Comment: 2. you are not "letting" $A\cup B\in P(A\cup B)$. 2.5. why is this necessary? Otherwise, it seems fine.

Comment: @KentaS because I have to use B⊆A ∪B in the following steps  but this is not covered in my lecture,so I cannot use it directly, so the only way is to include  B⊆B(this one is covered in lecture) and also the union concept to become B⊆A ∪B

Comment: @KentaS i edited the let part(2.), thank q for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative way to write this proof, let's try and see if we can unwrap the definitions, and then calculate our way towards the desired conclusion.$%
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
%$

For any $\;A,B\;$ we have
$$\calc
    P(A \cup B) \subseteq P(A) \cup P(B)
\op\equiv\hint{definitions of $\;\subseteq\;$ and $\;\cup\;$}
    \langle \forall D :: D \in P(A \cup B) \;\then\; D \in P(A) \lor D \in P(B) \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;P(\cdot)\;$, three times}
    \langle \forall D :: D \subseteq A \cup B \;\then\; D \subseteq A \lor D \subseteq B \rangle
\op\then\hints{choose $\;D:=A\;$; choose $\;\ldots\;$}\hint{-- introducing our targets $\;A \subseteq B\;$ and $\;\ldots\;$}
    (A \subseteq A \cup B \;\then\; A \subseteq A \lor A \subseteq B) \;\lor\; \ldots
\op\equiv\hint{simplify}
    \ldots
\endcalc$$

Now it should not be difficult to complete the proof.

As an exercise, you could compare this style of proof (pioneered by Edsger W. Dijkstra, see e.g. his [EWD1300](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html) whose notation I used above) with a traditional proof like in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3759347/11994.

$%
\endgroup
%$